# Unity3D build for Linux doesn't work

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, mono

i have an application(server app) which made on Unity for Linux (x86_64) with Headless mode. My system is Centos 7 x64, no GUI with installed mono. I tried next steps:

1. `mono ./server.x86_64 -batchmode -nographics`

answer:

```
Cannot open assembly './server.x86_64': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

2. `./server.x86_64 -batchmode -nographics`

answer:

`Set current directory to /usr/server_Linux_x86_64 Found path:` `/usr/server_Linux_x86_64/server.x86_64 Mono path[0] =` `'/usr/server_Linux_x86_64/server_Data/Managed' Mono path[1] =` `'/usr/server_Linux_x86_64/server_Data/Mono' Mono config path =` `'/usr/server_Linux_x86_64/server_Data/Mono/etc'`

and nothing happens...

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `mono ./server.x86_64` maybe just give the filename to mono, without a dot-slash? `mono server.x86_64 -batchmode -nographics`. But if you got output without explicitily opening it with mono, maybe your second command implicitly opened it with mono.

Comment: I've tried with and without dots, and other variants. All the same...

Comment: What output are you expecting from your server? What version of `mono` are you running? Maybe you could atleast test if it gets to the entry point of your application by immediatly `Debug.Log()`-ing something. Does the console line "hang" when you start your server or does the application exit and you get back to your shell?

Comment: Mono version (Stable 4.0.4.1). I'm not pro in linux, but i can see this server (with -batchmode -nographics) in processes on windows . No any processes on linux.

Comment: You can check for process by doing `ps aux | grep server`. On http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html it says that "Normally output_log.txt is written in the *_Data folder next to the game executable, where Debug.Log output is printed.". Did you check in the `/usr/server_Linux_x86_64/server_Data/` directories if any of your `Debug.Log()`s show up there? Otherwise, it would good if you would create a minimum working project with just a few Debug.Log()s, to check if Unity, Mono or your application is at fault here

Comment: There are no any log file in this folder, i tried to log when i run application, and log same as 2 point of my question. It's very confusing.

Comment: Any progress on this problem?